# Grunt and Uglify, running more than one task?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-uglify

I have a Grunt files as follows,

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
 pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

 'uglify': {
    options: {
        preserveComments: 'some',
    },
    my_target: {
      files: {
        'site/assets/js/js_code.js': [
            /* Libs */
            '/js/libs/jquery_2.2.4.min.js',
            '/js/libs/underscore_1.8.3.min.js',
            '/js/libs/backbone_1.3.3.min.js',

            /* Plugins */
            '/js/plugins/dropzone.min.js',
            '/js/plugins/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js',
            '/js/plugins/jquery.validate.min.js',

            /* Build JS Functions */
            '/js/functions.js',
            '/js/builder.js',

        ]
      }
    }
 }, 

 'sass': {
    dist: {
      options: {
        style: 'expanded',  
        compass: true,
      }, 
      files: {
        'assets/css/styles.css': '/scss/styles.scss',
      } //End of Files
    } //End of Dist.
 }, //End of SASS

 watch: {
  'JS': {
    files: ['/js/*.js'],
    tasks: ['uglify'],
    options: { spawn: false },
  },
 'Scss': {
    files: ['/scss/*.scss'],
    tasks: ['sass'],
    options: { spawn: false },
  } 
}
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
};
```

What I can not work out, and I have done lots of research but cant seems to find an answer, is how to set up uglify to have more than one task.

I know I can set up more than one file target but I dont want my watch to running these. So I want to be setup a 'libs.js', 'plugins.js' and something like 'my_code.js'. But I don't want the libs and plugins to be run each time my code is edited/updated. But what to be able to set it up in a way so that I can run something like, `grunt uglify-libs`.

Is that doable?

Many thanks

**UPDATE**

As per comments below, I try to explain in more detail.
Right now, I run `grunt watch` Which returns one output file.

I want to change this to have three output files, one for the libs files, one for the plugins and the other would be the code I write.

So when I run `Grunt watch`, that would only watch the files in my code but not any of the libs or plugins files.

Then I want to be able to run, `Grunt uglify-libs`, this would then make the libs file.

Same goes for the plugins, but something like, `Grunt uglify-plugs`.

So basically I want three uplify tasks but only one of them is run within the watch function.

Hope that help explain more.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you right, you want to use one grunt-command to start multiple tasks. You can do this by creating a "parent" tasks, who calls multiple sub-tasks like this:

```
  grunt.registerTask('uglify-libs', ['sass', 'uglify']);
```

Comment: sorry, I explain more - I very bad at asking question:( - I run 'grunt watch' which, right now, puts all my JS files into one file, but I want to split the files up, one for all my libs, plugins and the code I write. But I only want my watch command to run on my code and not concat / minify the libs or plugins files. I have on other projects, spilt the files up, so I know that is doable but I only want the watch to run on the code I write. But still enable to run something like 'grunt uglify-libs' and that one command will update just my libs file.

Comment: @C0ol_Cod3r Sorry, I simply don't get it :(

Comment: I have update the questions with an update that hopefully explains a little more I want to be able to do